# Payload undefined in dispatch handled within .then

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

I fetch UI elements' names in corresponding language from endpoint and get the result logged in console, I get the info in Postman, but nothing gets written in action's payload. I use redux-toolkit and maybe I don't get it, but I think that I don't need to dispatch anything here asynchronously. Here is the code:

```
// i18n.js

export const i18nSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'navigation',
    initialState,
    reducers: {
        setNavigationButtons: (state, action) => {
            console.log(action)
            state.navbar = action.payload;
        },


export const { setNavigationButtons } = i18nSlice.actions

export default i18nSlice.reducer
```

> The component with request:

```
 // Navbar.jsx

const navbarValues = useSelector((state) => state.i18n.navbar);
const dispatch = useDispatch();

const language = localStorage.getItem("lang") || "en";

 useEffect(() => {
        fetch(`http://localhost:3001/i18n?${new URLSearchParams({"lang": language})}`)
                .then(res => res.json())
                .then(res => dispatch(setNavigationButtons(res)))
        }, [])
```

Please, explain whether this dispatch should be made asynchronously and why or point to the mistake which provokes `action.payload` to be `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it is strange and I don't really understand the reason behind it, but I guess it is related to promise chaining somehow. I had `console.log`s between the `.then` statements and passed `res` to them. When I removed this logs, dispatch finally worked.

Comment: The `console.log` method's return value is always `undefined`. Does that help with understanding the reason behind it?

Comment: Yes, I guess :) 
Thank you a lot. Forgot the basics of JS